# Best translation of "binoculars": gemelos, binoculares, or prismáticos

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

Wiktionary lists three possible translations for "binoculars":

[image]

- gemelos
- binoculares
- prismáticos

Google translate prefers *binoculares*, but also offers *prismáticos* as an alternative.

Which is the most universally preferred translation?

Comment: Also: binóculo, gemelos prismáticos.

Comment: Aunque en la práctica binoculares y prismáticos son lo mismo, hay que aclarar que algunos binoculares **no** son prismáticos. Por ejemplo, el objeto de tu foto y los conocidos como "binocurales de ópera" o "de teatro", si los desmontas no tienen ningún prisma que facilite la visión estereoscópica. La luz pasa directa. En realidad son dos telescopios, uno para cada ojo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents: I favor `prismáticos` in *Castillian* Spanish.

To me `gemelos`, although can be used in this context is a word that makes me think of other things, like *cufflinks* (or twins). Also, I think that `gemelos` are a smaller set of binoculars (the ones you would see rich people have at their balconies at the opera house in the movies).

`Binoculares` is perfectly fine, but would be my second choice after `prismáticos`. I don't have a rationale for this, and may change among countries.

To answer your question I used google trends for [*binoculares*](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=binoculares) and [*prismáticos*](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=prismaticos) and the latter seems to be used almost exclusively in Spain (plus Argentina, Chile and Mexico), so **I guess `binoculares` is more widely accepted**, if we are to listen to Google trends.

I would compare it too with "gemelos", but as you know that is also Spanish for "twins", "cufflinks" and some muscles in your legs (calves), so Google trends would not help here.

Comment: RAE's frequency list agrees for «binoculares» vs «prismáticos». I didn't look for «gemelos» because I have no way to exclude the «twins» sense. Also, «anteojos» seems quite frequent too.

Comment: @guillem Gracias!! No conocía ese recurso de la RAE.

Comment: @guillem yo sacaría "anteojos" ya que es más usado para hacer referencia a lentes o gafas recetadas.

Comment: @sergio-velásquez aunque el DRAE favorece la visión de larga distancia en sus dos primeras entradas (y en España, cuando he oído la palabra, ha sido ¿siempre? con ese sentido), veo que Google Images da muchas gafas y pocos binoculares. No sé si es una diferencia dialectal, pero supongo que esa debe de ser la razón de la alta frecuencia.

Comment: En Chile ambas palabras se usan, pero suenan "técnicas". Generalmente decimos "me compré unos _largavistas_".

Answer (score 3):

"Binoculares" is the most universally preferred translation. In other countries, it's also known as "Largavistas".

Answer (score 3):

`Binoculares` is used pretty widely, I've read `prismáticos` in literature from Spain and Argentina, but binoculares is probably more widely understood. As for `gemelos`, I've never encountered it in this context.