# chabacano, hortera, cursi, ramplón

Tags: diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

According to Word Reference, "[chabacano](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=chabacano)", "[hortera](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=hortera)", "[cursi](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=cursi)" and "[ramplón](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=rampl%C3%B3n)" are all synonyms of "tacky", "tasteless" (= in bad taste). DLE definitions also look very similar:

[chabacano](https://dle.rae.es/chabacano)

1. adj. Grosero o de mal gusto.

[hortera](https://dle.rae.es/hortera)

1. adj. despect. coloq. Vulgar y de mal gusto.

[ramplón](https://dle.rae.es/rampl%C3%B3n)

1. adj. Vulgar, chabacano.

[cursi](https://dle.rae.es/cursi)

1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que pretende ser elegante y refinada sin conseguirlo.
2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que, con apariencia de elegancia o delicadeza, es pretenciosa y de mal gusto.

Is there any difference in meaning or usage? Can all these words be used for people and things?

Comment: Probably location-dependent, in a very localized sense. I am only used to "cursi" and "hortera" with basically the same meaning.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  If you give us a particular context then I think it would be answerable.  To get you started: the only one I know (Mexico) in this group is *cursi*.  "Tacky" is a good word for it.  "Kitsch" would also work.  *Grosero* and *vulgar* are stronger, I think, with *vulgar* the strongest, and the more formal choice.  There's also *feo* and *asqueoso* (disgusting).  As an exclamation: *¡Fuchi!*  To get a feel for usage you need to check several sources that give plenty of examples.  (*Chabacano* I only know as the fruit.

Comment: I don't know if it's too broad, but it's certainly answerable only by a very diligent examination of a lot of localized examples. Probably not useful, too. I will only say that I disagree with the definition of *cursi* and I think *hortera* is exclusively European.

Comment: @pablodf76 Why do you disagree with the definition of "cursi"? What does it mean in Argentina?

Comment: For me, only "chabacano" and "ramplón" can be used interchangeably. "Hortera" is more used with other meaning, and so is "cursi" with another different meaning.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. I don't find it as different as others we have had like [“Gafas” vs “anteojos” vs “lentes” vs “espejuelos” in Mexican Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10423/5481) or [Best translation of “binoculars”: gemelos, binoculares, or prismáticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13486/5481).

Comment: @Diego - I probably won't persuade you to my point of view, and that's okay -- but I'll explain my vote to close.  If someone asks about two different words and their differences, that's doable, especially if they let us know what they're hoping to express -- with the context.  But with four words, and no context -- I think one would have to write an extensive dictionary entry to answer this with such a broad scope.

Comment: * I have a typo above -- it should be *asqueroso*.

Comment: I heard my grandparents use *chabacano* and *cursi*. None of those words are in use now in Colombia. If you hear them it would be from a very old person, so I guess this question needs a region tag.

Comment: @DGaleano which words with this meaning are in use nowadays in Colombia ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Aparte de **ordinario** que sería la palabra formal tenemos [mañé](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Ma%C3%B1%C3%A9.php), [chirrete](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Chirrete.php), [valija](https://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/valija) y tal vez algunas más.

Answer (score 2):

La vulgaridad y el mal gusto se manifiestan de muchas maneras.

**Chabacano** Es algo barato o de calidad infima, o una persona con malos modales o poca educación.

**Hortera** Es algo que no va a la moda o con escasa combinación de colores y estilos.

**Ramplón** Algo tosco, sin pulir, primitivo, basto.

**Cursi** Que pretende tener apariencia de refinado sin serlo.

Answer (score 1):

hortera is in general, someone with bad taste, not following the tendencies. Example: 'es un hortera, está pasado de moda'.

'es un cursi por llevar tanto rosa' => too girly.

'Tiene una manera de vestir muy chabacana' => rough, countryside, looking tough not in a good way.

'es muy ramplón vistiendo' => it is too simple when dressing

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/cursi gives a different meaning of "cursi". Maybe that meaning you gave is a regionalism of the place you live?

Comment: perhaps. I used to live in central Spain